# updating database failed from android phone

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new in database, and I want to update my database (MySql, I am using MAMP) from the android phone. 
The following code is working when I use the same wireless network on android, but it is not working when the server and android phone network are different. 
Anyone have any idea what is the problem?

```
kHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
File cacheDirectory = new File(this.getCacheDir(),"http");
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
Cache cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);
client.setCache(cache);
Request request = new     Request.Builder().url("http://192.168.xxx.yyy:8888/myFirstPHP.php").build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
        updateTextView1();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.code() >= 200 || response.code() <= 300){
            ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();
            InputStream inputStream = responseBody.byteStream();
            updateTextView();
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

192.168.x.x it is a private ip, therefore, it is private and not accessible from outside of your network.

In order to access it from outside, try using the public ip.
details:

[private ip vs public ip](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address)

*EDIT*

Port forwarding start:
[Setup port forwarding](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router)

The above might not be the general solution, as there different vendors, but it should give you a start.

Comment: Thanks, I understand I have to use a public ip, but what is my public ip on my mac?

Comment: Also when I change it to my public ip, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You will have to setup port forwarding on your modem/router and point your external IP to your Macbook.

Comment: Would you explain it simpler? I am really new in this field.